# Xamarin : set different background to each tab (in TabHost)

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.android, xamarin

I am trying to add background to each tab in TabHost.

```
private void CreateTab(Type activityType, string tag, string label, int drawableId)
    {
        TabHost.TabSpec spec;

        var intent = new Intent(this, activityType);
        intent.AddFlags(ActivityFlags.NewTask);

        spec = TabHost.NewTabSpec(tag);
        var drawableIcon = Resources.GetDrawable(drawableId);
        spec.SetIndicator(label, drawableIcon);
        spec.SetContent(intent);

        TabHost.AddTab(spec);
    }
```

I use the above code to create tabs.

Please help,
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I Got it working, Here is the code

```
TabWidget.GetChildAt(0).SetBackgroundColor(Color.PaleGreen); //1st tab
```